# Facebook signup form via iframe

Tags: facebook, iframe

I have created a sign up page to be used via iframe as a sign up page. I was wondering how can I show a different page (redirect?) if the user has all ready used the contact form, is this possible? Thanks

Comment: Is this inside of a facebook app?  Can you be more explicit about the relationship between the contact form and the sign up page?

Comment: Sure, it's a facebook iframe app, I have an external page which is pulled in via an iframe.

Comment: yes, you can just do a simple redirect inside an iframe.  Treat the iframe like an independent browser window.  You can do just about anything you want inside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside your sign up page

```
<% if (customer_has_used_contact_form()) %>
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.location="somewhere_else.html";
</script>

<% end %>
```